# Suggestions using Query function in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Thank you for helping me out last time. I hope this time you can help me out to. See the following screenshots:

```
<https://ibb.co/ZhP6Vhz>
<https://ibb.co/bQZcV7v>
<https://ibb.co/sgr5s6g>
<https://ibb.co/QnypvJc>
```

What I would like to achieve is the following. In cell "J2" I can select the name of the symbol I want. If this symbol is a Long-term investment or Short-term investment (data in Positions!F4:F30), then I want it to return table "Stock". If it is a cryptocurrency, then I want it to return table "Crypto".

I know I can use the query function for this but my brain keeps giving me an error. I hope there is someone out there that can give me some advice!
Thanks much in advance.

If someone wants me to share it, here is the link:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqyAQd8t00qAcbusTFLYMG0eleRwuGq3mJCzI1pF0oI/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot open your sample Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Please share the spreadsheet with edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
=ALS.FOUT(ALS(VERT.ZOEKEN($J1;Positions!$A3:$F;6;ONWAAR)="Short-term investment";query(Stock;"select * where A is not null");
        ALS(VERT.ZOEKEN($J1;Positions!$A3:$F;6;ONWAAR)="Long-term investment";query(Stock;"select * where A is not null");              ALS(VERT.ZOEKEN($J1;Positions!$A3:$F;6;ONWAAR)="Cryptocurrency";query(Crypto;"select * where D is not null");)));)
```